# My array search in Java will not work

Tags: java, arrays

I have created an array of 3 different people's "checking account info," and I need to be able to use the rest of the customer's data in other parts of my code if an input from a user matches one of the customer's "account number" in my array.

For example, if a user inputs 12345678, my code will need to search the array, match that input with "Jon's" account, and then use Jon's info for other things in the code. I am basically writing ATM software.

My problem lies in matching the account number to the inputs from the user. The account numbers are the last elements in each part of the "cac" array.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

```
CheckingAccountCustomer[] cac = new CheckingAccountCustomer[3]; // array of checking account customers, names, pins, balances, account numbers
    cac[0] = new CheckingAccountCustomer("Joe", 1234, 5000, 11111111);
    cac[1] = new CheckingAccountCustomer("Bob", 1111, 9000, 24606069);
    cac[2] = new CheckingAccountCustomer("Jon", 2222, 40000, 12345678);



    // prompt user for account number
    System.out.print("Please insert Debit Card or enter account number (8 digits):\n");
    sc.nextLine();
    int accountNumber = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < cac; i++)
    {
        if (accountNumber == cac[i][3])

            // DO STUFF WITH OTHER DATA
    }
```

Comment: what is the error you are seeing ?

Comment: where "cac[i][3]" is, my compiler is saying that "This type of expression must be an array type, but it resolved to CheckingAccountCustomer"

Comment: Maybe you want `cac[i].accountNumber`? You wrote the `CheckingAccountCustomer` class, not us.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your for statement should read:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cac.length; i++)
```

And second: the reference `cac[i][3]` might be wrong too, depending on the definition of the `CheckingAccountCustomer` class.

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be `i < cac.length` not `cac`, since `cac` is an array.

In any way please use a `Map` where key is that desired number, it would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You're not properly iterating across the array.  You should be using the following for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cac.length; i++) {

}
```

Also, you've got another interesting problem.  `accountNumber == cac[i][3]` is not valid, since `cac` is only a one-dimensional array.  If we remove the extra dimension access, you're left with `accountNumber == cac[i]`.

But we have *another* interesting problem.  Why would an `int` equal `CheckingAccountCustomer`?  That will never be true.

What you want to use is some sort of accessor on the object's account number instead.

So, altogether, your for-loop should read like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cac.length; i++) {
    if(accountNumber == cac[i].getAccountNumber()) {
        // logic.
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the best option for me to use, however I did not have an accessor, and I am having trouble writing that now.

Would it be something like:
return cac[i][3]
?

Comment: No.  The statement you're attempting is referencing a two-dimensional array, which is something you don't have.  An accessor is something on the `CheckingAccountCustomer` that returns specific information, such as the account number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the array.  The conditional statement in the for loop is checking if an `int` is greater than an `CheckingAccountCustomer[]`, instead of the length of the array.

The conditional `if` statement is also comparing a `int` to a `CheckingAccountCustomer` which will evaluate, you need to get the account number from the `CheckingAccountCustomer`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cac.length; i++)
{
    if (accountNumber == cac[i][3].getAccountNumber())

        // DO STUFF WITH OTHER DATA
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "foreach" syntax for your loop:

```
for :CheckingAccountCustomer c : cac) {
    if (c.getAccountNumber() == accountNumber)

}
```

Note that I hve asumed you have an accessor method for accountNumber.